# K4iOS Media Query

Tags: kindle, media-queries

Does anyone know of a way to target K4iOS with a media query?

Like this: https://gist.github.com/dvschultz/8324974 but with Kindle for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to do (though I did read your recent MobileRead postings on the subject).  What use case are you trying to solve for? Reading on iPhones at night?

Here's my thoughts on the subject. [Media queries to distinguish between Kindle e-inks vs non-e-inks](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/6552/media-queries-to-distinguish-between-kindle-e-inks-vs-non-e-inks/6555#6555)

I decided not to bother with iOS-specific media queries because I thought the CSS media breakpoints worked well enough to make them unnecessary.

By the way, if you haven't done so already, I recommend that you download the new Kindle Previewer Beta version (which makes it a little easier to produce files for iPad/iOS devices. http://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html?docId=1003018611)

I have had flaky results on embedded fonts and font effects across platforms (even on Google Play Books -- which doesn't make sense at all). I have added a few embedded fonts and done a little testing, but I don't require that my ebooks render it correctly.

I have slightly lower standards for how ebooks render in Kindle for iOS. (My thought is that if people want to buy something for an Apple device, they could always buy from the Apple store or buy the no-DRM epub files my company sells and import them into iBooks).

My Kindle formatting issues hinged mainly on image rendering and positioning, not so much on font effects, so my solution of not targeting iOS devices but keeping the breakpoints generic  may not work for you...

Comment: Well, there are two separate questions: targeting Kindle Fire Night Mode, and targeting K4iOS. Their use cases overlap, but they're separate things. I seem to have the K4iOS thing figured out though, as noted in my MobileRead posts: "target K4iOS" is actually wrong, I want to target non-e-ink. Funny that @HonzaHejzl couldn't get his queries to work...maybe I'll post mine on his question. Overall, thank you :)